# Disabling "Use default gateway" on TCP/IPv4 kills the VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, tcpip

My work network requires you to disable the default gateway to use home directories etc. remotely. However, disabling the default gateway disables the VPN connection. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us a bit more information to work with, like your OS, VPN software, where you are disabling your default gateway....you'll get out of this question what you put into it, promise!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is probably to add a static route for the IP endpoint of the VPN (and ensure the VPN provides the default gateway, which I suspect is happening at the moment, and causing things to break).

What I suspect is going on now is that you have a regular Internet connection with a default gateway.  You then tell the VPN software to connect to another point on the Internet.  If the VPN server is set to allow you to route all traffic through it, it publishes a new default gateway to you, which is overriding your regular gateway.  As a result, your VPN client no longer has a valid route to the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Default Gateway is used by the PC to reach to any machine / IP which does not belong to the subnet in which the PC is. So basically anything that needs to be routed is sent to the default gateway (access to Google, internet etc.)

So if you remove the default gateway, you will only have access to your Homegroup and machines on the same subnet (that packets will be switched). Now VPN needs internet access, so it needs a default gateway to reach the internet/ VPN server.